# geting icon by name is not working

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I can't get icon lookup by name to work correctly. I copied the code from Gallery examples and repeated the same configuration in my project, but it doesn't work.

This is what I did:

1.Copy icons/gallery into the directory of my own project, this is the list of files:

```
icons/default
icons/default/20x20@3
icons/default/20x20@3/back.png
icons/default/20x20@3/menu.png
icons/default/20x20@3/drawer.png
icons/default/20x20@4
icons/default/20x20@4/back.png
icons/default/20x20@4/menu.png
icons/default/20x20@4/drawer.png
icons/default/20x20
icons/default/20x20/back.png
icons/default/20x20/menu.png
icons/default/20x20/drawer.png
icons/default/index.theme
icons/default/20x20@2
icons/default/20x20@2/back.png
icons/default/20x20@2/menu.png
icons/default/20x20@2/drawer.png
```

2.Added `index.theme` file into theme directory:

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=default
Comment=Qt Quick Controls 2 Gallery Example Icon Theme

Directories=20x20,20x20@2,20x20@3,20x20@4

[20x20]
Size=20
Type=Fixed

[20x20@2]
Size=20
Scale=2
Type=Fixed

[20x20@3]
Size=20
Scale=3
Type=Fixed

[20x20@4]
Size=20
Scale=4
Type=Fixed
```

3.Added corresponding lines to main.cpp, to enable icons, this is the code:

```
QGuiApplication::setApplicationName("MyApp");
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QIcon::setThemeName("default");
QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;    
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;
return app.exec();
```

In a QML file I use the icon this way:

```
ToolButton {
    icon.name: "menu"
}
```

If I lookup by URL, it works fine:

```
ToolButton {
    icon.source: "qrc:/icons/default/20x20/menu.png"
}
```

So, what could be the reason of why lookup by name doesn't work and how to debug this ?

EDIT:

After Mitch's answer I found that icon's weren't working because the ":/icons" entry in the icon's path wasn't the first one.

So, this code DOESN'T work:

```
QIcon::setThemeName("default");
QStringList list;
list<<":/icons";
list<<"/usr/share/icons";
QIcon::setThemeSearchPaths(list);
```

However, this cdoe DOES work:

```
QIcon::setThemeName("default");
QStringList list;
list<<":/icons";
list<<"/usr/share/icons";
QIcon::setThemeSearchPaths(list);
```

To make it work you only need to make the path where your icons are located, first entry in list.

But maybe it is a bug, I am using Qt 5.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list of things you did is exhaustive, then you [missed a step](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-icons.html):

> Traditionally, only Linux and UNIX support icon themes on the platform level, but it is possible to bundle a compliant icon theme in an application to use themed icons on any platform.
>
> The default icon theme search paths depend on the platform. On Linux and UNIX, the search path will use the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable if available. All platforms have the resource directory :/icons as a fallback. Custom icon theme search paths can be set with QIcon::setThemeSearchPaths().
>
> The following example bundles an icon theme called mytheme into the application's resources using Qt's resource system.
>
> ```
> <RCC>
>     <qresource prefix="/">
>         <file>icons/mytheme/index.theme</file>
>         <file>icons/mytheme/32x32/myicon.png</file>
>         <file>icons/mytheme/32x32@2/myicon.png</file>
>     </qresource>
> </RCC>
> ```

After creating that file, you also need to add it to your `.pro`.

Comment: It worked, thanks. But I printed icons path with `qDebug() << "icons path" << QIcon::themeSearchPaths();` and the output was:   `icons path ("/usr/share/icons", ":/icons")` . So, apparently 2 entries in list won't work???. Only after I set it again within main.cpp like `QIcon::setThemeSearchPaths(QStringList() << ":/icons");` , it worked. So, apparently, the `":/icons"` path was at second position in the list and this is why it didn't worked by default.

Comment: definitely it doesn't work if `:/icons` isn't the first entry, I have edited my question to show that. Thanks again!